# Is there a way to find nth largest value with multiple criteria in excel?

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to extract a summary of information for a particular client. Using the following formula:

```
{=LARGE(IF('claims history'!$B:$B=$C$2,'claims history'!$AF:$AF),1)}
```

I am able to extract the largest claim (`$AF:$AF`) within a client's (`$B:$B=$C$2`) claims history.

However, I want to add an additional criteria to this, so that I can pull out the largest claim per defined year (`'claims history'!$J:$J`).

How to implement this into the above formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a trick with array formulae when using `AND` doesn't work - that is to multiply your conditions in the `IF` expression.

In your example, assuming that the year is in cell `D2` you would do:

```
{=LARGE(IF(('claims history'!$B:$B=$C2)*('claims history'!$J:$J=$D2),('claims history'!$AF:$AF)),1)}
```

Note: If you think that `TRUE` is **1** and `FALSE` is **0** then you can see that multiplying gives us an `AND`... and also adding will give an `OR`

Comment: Hi Captain, thank you for taking the time to reply. Unfortunately my formulae are still coming back with #NA. However, I now realise it is an issue with way our data is recorded.

Instead of having years like 2012, 2013, etc. The years are recorded as "Current" "-1" "-2" etc. If I switch the criteria to the year of the claim then your suggestion works perfectly. However, I cannot change the way we record the policy year, do you know why this is returning errors?

Comment: Hi. I suspect that there are some values with errors in your years range. Because the array formula looks at the entire of column J, if there is even one error value then it will return error. Option 1: make sure there are no errors. Option 2: wrap the year part in an `IFERROR` --> `{=LARGE(IF(('claims history'!$B:$B=$C2)*(IFERROR('claims history'!$J:$J=$D2,0)),('claims history'!$AF:$AF)),1)}`

Comment: Thanks again Captain! I've got the formulae working now, just had to remove error values from Column J